# yii framework. cats tree functions aren`t working in the model file

Tags: php, yii

```
 public function getCats($model){

    $levels = array();
    $tree = array();
    $cur = array();

    foreach($model as $rows){

        $cur = &$levels[$rows['id']];
        $cur['parent_id'] = $rows['parent_id'];
        $cur['title'] = $rows['title'];

        if($rows['parent_id'] == 0){
            $tree[$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }
        else{
            $levels[$rows['parent_id']]['children'][$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }

    }
    return $tree;

}

public function getTree($arr){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){

            echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="/page/index/id/'.$k.'">'.$v['title'].'</a>';
                    if(!empty($v['children'])){
                        echo getTree($v['children']);
                    }
            echo '</li>';

        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
public function allCats($pos) {
    $model = Category::model()->findallBySql('SELECT id, parent_id, title FROM {{category}} WHERE position="'.$pos.'"');
    $cats = getCats($model); 
    echo getTree($cats); 
}
```

I wonder, why these functions don`t work in model file(inside class)? 
If i use them inside controllers, they work fine, and if i paste them inside model(class) file, they stop working(as if they are becoming invisible). The last function causing the above two functions.

Comment: Please post the relevant controller code since it's very unclear how everythng is called.

Comment: `<?php

class TreeController extends Controller
{
 public function actionIndex()
 {
  $this->render('index');
 }
}` hope, you meant this code?!

Comment: Well yes but that doesn't help. Where do you call that `getCats()`? In the view? If so you cannot use `$this` cause it would point you to the controller. You have to use `$model->getCats($mode)` which is a bit redundant but should work.

Comment: i'm doing like this. i created helper class and pasted all my(three)functions there. And then, i'm calling each function individually in the view file:
`$allCats = Ttree::allCats('top');
$data = Ttree::getCats($allCats);
$getTree = Ttree::getTree($data);
echo $getTree;`
and it works fine, without any problems and errors. 
anyway, thank you  very much. Without your hint, I would not have come to a such decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getCats($model)` which would be a global function. But it's defined as a class function/method. Call it `$this->getCats($model)` and `$this->getTree($cats)` and it should work.

Comment: yes, I've tried it, but i am getting  this error: TreeController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getCats".

Comment: Wait, where is `getCats()` defined? In the model or in the controller?

Comment: both(getTree, getCats) are defined in the model. If i use them in the controller, i have no problem(almost).

Comment: Should work in the model. What is the excact error message you get?

Comment: in the error list(page) i have these marked lines:

/var/www/yiicms.loc/framework/base/CComponent.php(266)
throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "{name}".',

/var/www/yiicms.loc/protected/models/Tree.php(55): CComponent->__call("getCats", array(array(Category, Category))) 

$this ->getCats($model); 

/var/www/yiicms.loc/protected/controllers/TreeController.php(87): CController->render("index") 

$this->render('index');

and so on. They are too many to write all of them here

Comment: Maybe i should call function by another method in the index file?

Comment: What is in Tree.php on line 55? And what in TreeController.php on line 87?

Comment: on line 55(Tree.php): $this ->getCats($model); and on line 87(TreeController.php) $this->render('index'); In the TreeController file i have only one function(function actionIndex and rendering it to the index file), nothing more.